# Which one is active? How to switch it off? Or Switch GPU? Switchable Graphics Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: 14.04, graphics, hybrid-graphics

This is what I get when I run lshw. Which one is active?

```
rahul@rahul-hp-dv6-dev-pc:~$ sudo lshw -c display
[sudo] password for rahul: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:c4400000-c441ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c4440000-c445ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5050(size=8)
rahul@rahul-hp-dv6-dev-pc:~$
```

---

Update: as per answer from zhongfu

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

output:

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
2:DIS-Audio: :Pwr:0000:01:00.1
```

**DIS is not off. But DynPwr. Which I guess is dynamic power.
How to switch it off. Or Switch GPU?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open *System Settings* and click *Details*. The graphics card you're currently using for Unity and (probably) all your applications should be shown besides "Graphics".

However, if you want to know which card(s) are powered on, you can run:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

It should show something like this:

```
0:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

The two entries refer to the two GPUs: the **dis**crete GPU, i.e. AMD, or **i**nte**g**rate**d** GPU, i.e. Intel. `Off` means the GPU is off, and `Pwr` means the GPU is on.

Comment: Hmm: `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
cat: /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: No such file or directory`

Comment: Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and add `modeset=1` right before the quotation mark at end of the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, then run `sudo update-grub` and restart when that completes. Try the command again after it reboots.

Comment: I am using GNOME.

Comment: `0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
2:DIS-Audio: :Pwr:0000:01:00.1`

@zhongfu thanks

how do i switch between them?

Comment: You probably need to do something more complicated to switch between them, probably involving installing proprietary drivers for your GPU, and logging off and logging in again every time you switch it. [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/522177/intel-amd-hybrid-graphics-on-ubuntu-14-04?answertab=votes#tab-top) might help with your question.

Comment: If you want to switch it off, try running `echo OFF | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`, and check with `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`.