# Laptop Screen Rapidly Flashes Off/On/Off/On... at Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers

I have an Asus laptop with a Radeon HD 8650G (although the sticker says 8670M) graphics card dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04. When I start the computer, I get to the GRUB boot options menu and select Ubuntu. While Ubuntu is booting from GRUB the screen flashes. If I boot to windows from the Windows Boot Manager option, this does not happen. The lspci -v command lists radeon as my kernel driver in use.

I'm concerned that this problem could be bad for my graphics card.

Does anybody know what the problem could be and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop have double GPU ? (integrated GPU and AMD Radeon)
If yes, then try to read the post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522177/intel-amd-hybrid-graphics-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Generally, this issue is due to the non fully support for AMD and Nvidia drivers on Linux, the best solution is to use the integrated GPU instead of the AMD one.